# Invalid sunrise/set times?

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I'm getting bogus values for sunrise/set times (e.g. for Nevada):

```
let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Nevada,us&APPID=<app_id>&units=metric"
let req = new Request(url)
let json = await req.loadJSON()

function convertTime(unixTime){
    let dt = new Date(unixTime * 1000)
    let h = dt.getHours()
    let m = "0" + dt.getMinutes()
    let t = h + ":" + m.substr(-2)
    return t
}

let sRise = convertTime(json.sys.sunrise)
let sSet = convertTime(json.sys.sunset)

alert(convertTime(sRise));
// Shows: 14:32 should be 05:24

alert(convertTime(sSet));
// Shows: 05:10 should be 19:55
```

Am I missing something? (P.S. I'm in Europe but got the same results through a proxy).

Comment: It looks like you are specifically querying for Nevada, USA every time in your URL: `?q=Nevada,us`.  Perhaps if you want to change the locale put in something else.  For example `?q=Florence,it&APPID=<app_id>&units=metric`

Comment: No, it is correct; the times for Nevada are invalid. I'm not sure if it's from openweather or the time conversion function.

Comment: Its the time conversion function. By default, when you use `dt.getHours` it returns the hours *in local time*. It doesn't seem too unreasonable that 14:32 in Europe is sunrise in Nevada.

Comment: You're making a local Date with the timestamp returned, so JavaScript will think you want a date instance for **your** time zone, not the target time zone.

Comment: The date/time returned from the API is UTC.

Comment: Consider ditching your `convertTime` function in favor of the much more flexible and built in [`Date.toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString).

Comment: @BerinLoritsch yes, and `new Date()` will assume that, but when you start plucking the time information out of the instance it'll be according to the local time in the browser.

Comment: @Pointy, it's there: https://openweathermap.org/current about halfway down the page.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch ah I was looking at the wrong call, thanks

Comment: NOTE: the `timezone` data element returned along with the `sys` one has the shift in seconds for (I believe) the target time zone from UTC.

Comment: @all Thx! That was it; the time is offset ~ -9 hrs compared to Central Europe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Weather API (https://openweathermap.org/current) has another data element that helps convert the UTC time provided by the `sys` object to the time that is local for the requested area.  Your conversion function needs to account for the offset.  Example:

```
let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Nevada,us&APPID=<app_id>&units=metric"
let req = new Request(url)
let json = await req.loadJSON()

function convertTime(unixTime, offset){
    let dt = new Date((unixTime + offset) * 1000)
    let h = dt.getHours()
    let m = "0" + dt.getMinutes()
    let t = h + ":" + m.substr(-2)
    return t
}

let sRise = convertTime(json.sys.sunrise, json.timezone)
let sSet = convertTime(json.sys.sunset, json.timezone)

alert(convertTime(sRise));
// Shows: 05:24

alert(convertTime(sSet));
// Shows: 19:55
```